# Does this forecast visualisation make statistical sense?

Tags: data-visualization, prediction

The Met Office is the UK national weather service. Among it services, it provides assessment of upcoming storms in terms of their potential strength and consequences. This information is visually presented in what they call a "[Warning Impact Matrix](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/guide/weather/severe-weather-advice)". An example for the current storm is [here](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/public/weather/warnings#?date=2018-09-23), reproduced below:

[image]

The matrix shows two dimensions, namely severity of the impact and likelihood of the impact. It then selects one of the elements with a tick. But... anyone ever producing a statistical estimate knows that **an estimation provides a whole range of predictions with different probabilities**, with "extreme" values (i.e. those far from the mean estimate) having lower probability. This is oftentimes visualised as below:

[image]

In light of this, whatever the mean prediction is (maybe given by the tick in the matrix), the model could well predict **another square in the matrix**, e.g. that with highest and/or lowest impact being very unlikely. Hence, the actual matrix would be something like:

[image]

which not only looks less useful but kind of trivial (you can almost picture the pdf of the normal distribution building up in the above matrix!). Thus, the question is, does this representation make sense? Is it ever appropriate?

Comment: What should be the purpose of these extra ticks?

Comment: @JanKukacka Well, what is the purpose of the first tick? You can think of every square containing a given value of your forecast for a given confidence interval. You put a tick to whichever is consistent with the prediction. Clearly more than one (but not all of them) will be consistent. If you only put a tick for the mean prediction, you will never have ticks in the bottom rows. So why to bother with the matrix then...

Comment: I would assume the tick marks the expectation of the current storm, i.e. it will quite likely strike but won't be severe. I would also assume that other outcomes are also possible, but with decreasing probability as we move away from the tick. However, I have no clue what should your additional ticks mean.

Comment: @JanKukacka "...with decreasing probability as we move away from the tick." Precisely. Into the ""Unlikely" row. Hence the extra ticks. Imagine the pdf of a normal distribution with mean (median) close to the original tick. The two extra ticks also belong to the distribution.

Comment: But why should there be any ticks for the purpose? And why should there be no tick e.g. in the upper right corner which is just as far from the original tick as the lower left? You need to express yourself bit more clearly...

Comment: @JanKukacka The upper right is "very likely". Why would there be a tick there if there original tick is in position (2,2)? Why would they ever avoid the tick there (which is the most extreme scenario and thus relevant for the public, i.e. highly likely very severe storm) and put on in (2,2) instead?

Comment: As I understand it, the tick is not there because it is not "very likely" that there will be a "high impact" storm on the given day.

Comment: @luchonacho With this example you have nicely highlighted a very common problem whereby people report point estimates without reporting associated confidence intervals or credible intervals.This means oversimplification with regard to the topic and an expression of overconfidence on the part of the analyst.